# Hypernym for “import” and “export”?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What word could describe an operation of either importing or exporting?

*X* is to *import* and *export* as *migration* is to *immigration* and *emigration*.

*Porting* isn't the word I'm looking for, I don't think, but that's what I'm getting at. Cheers!

Comment: International commerce? In the USA, a business like that is called an import/export business.

Comment: how about trade?

Comment: *Art Vandelay.*

Comment: @Mitch I'd say make that an answer. That's as right as right can be.

Comment: Do you mean the noun or the verb?

Comment: Combining John's answer with Mitch's you get [*International Trade*](https://www.google.com/search?q=international+trade&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a),  which is a standard economic term.

Comment: This question needs more context specified to be answerable. Those terms are issued in the software world differently than they are in, say, international commerce.

Answer (score 6):

The right comparative, admittedly obscure, word is ***portation***, not *porting*.

> OED: the act of carrying or transferring.

Comment: Thanks! Would the hypernym of importer and exporter be porter?

Comment: No - that would be *portation* once again.

Comment: Wouldn't it be portator or something?

Comment: Perhaps, if there were good enough reasons.

Comment: @NickStrupat - I would say that would just be a transporter.

Answer (score 3):

As noted earlier, a more precise word will depend on the context:

- in the context of international commerce, import and export are both forms of international **trade**
- in the context of a single business, import and export are both forms of **transport** of goods or services (usually to or from a different country, but not always)
- in the context of software systems, import and export are usually both forms of **integration** between software systems, or in a somewhat more general sense, **data transfer** (or, less frequently, **data transport**)

Answer (score 2):

Combining suggestions:

> **International trade**

because import and export are by definition trade between countries.

Comment: and sometimes just ***trade***, as in ["balance of trade"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22balance+of+trade%22)

Answer (score 0):

As I just posted on another question that references this one:

> [Conveyance](http://gog.is/define+conveyance) - the action or process of transporting or carrying someone or something from one place to another.

This is completely applicable to the import and export of items between countries and borders.

Answer (score 0):

***inout*** is in current use to mean the export/import of data

> Elasticsearch InOut Plugin ..(P)rovides the ability to export data by
>   query on server side, by outputting the data directly on the according
>   node... The exported data can also be imported into elasticsearch
>   again.
>   https://github.com/crate/elasticsearch-inout-plugin

Answer (score -4):

One word to include Import/Export? 
What about the term "Commercial" which refers to commerce which in turn means "the exchange or buying and selling of commodities on a large scale involving transportation from place to place," according to Merriam Webster's Collegiate Dictionary: 10th Edition (1993).

Comment: "Commercial" isn't a noun, so isn't really what is requested. look a the first comment on this question to see the noun form of *commercial*