# What is a single word that means both 'Import' and 'Export'?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms, software

In my web application, I am importing and exporting users to/from the application. So, for that I would like to have a single word to generally represent 'Import/Export process'.

I've gone through [Hypernym for “import” and “export”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141717/hypernym-for-import-and-export). But it is talking about business trading and all. I'm not expecting that meaning for it.

So, please suggest one. Thanks :)

Comment: How about transfer?

Comment: In trade, the catchall term used in EXIM. Will that work for you?

Comment: Usually software menus just say import/export. While we could probably come up with something fancy (I'd vote for *porting*, I guess, or the obscure and silly-sounding but correct *portation*), the users would probably understand the plain old *import/export* better. You might also consider *synchronisation*, which looks cool, but has a bit different meaning.

Comment: *Transfer* means something different entirely. *Syncronization* or *converting* might or might not work, but really, as @SáT says, the convention is "Import/export". Though from the UI standpoint, looking for one label makes no sense at all because the two different actions should have two different menu entries. When I click on "import/export", how do you know if you should present me with a save file dialog or with an open file one? And if you are looking for a name for the menu to put both options in, that would be *File*. Another ubiquitous convention. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I totally agree with you. I'll give it as `Import/Export` only. Thanks :)

Comment: When designing software, worry less about trying to find the shortest term for everything (although brevity is a good thing, usually). Instead, the best thing you can do is examine how most other softare convey the same idea. This is why we still have icons that look like 3.5" floppy disks that everyone knows mean "save", even though half of those people probably don't remember floppy disks any more.

Comment: Converters? I have a file that has to list importers and exporters of certain file formats. So the file and list has to have a name to reflect that. Converters is the closest I have found but it doesn't sound right. I might post another question but it would probably get marked as a duplicate of this one. However I don't see an answer that seems acceptable to my case. Maybe codecs but that's seems to mean unreadable binary format where I want to encode to readable XML. Any suggestions appreciated. Edit: found another question that suggested transcoders or translators. Going with transcoders.

Comment: I haven't found a good word for this either, so I just have to stick with "Import/Export". "port" has several meanings in software already, neither of which really apply (you're not porting code, this isn't a port on a router, ...), "transfer" kind of works but may connote editing the status of the user; i.e., transferring departments, "convert" doesn't apply as the users aren't being changed, just moved or copied from somewhere, "move" or copy" is too generic, "conveyance" may imply an automatic process even if you mean a manual one and also sounds awkward to me, the list goes on

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in your question.

**Port**

> Computing:
>   transfer (software) from one system or machine to another.

Comment: port has a very common technical meaning, as in a socket port: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking) which could prove confusing

In my opinion, this is a better question for https://ux.stackexchange.com/

See here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/106584/another-way-for-saying-importing-and-exporting

Answer (score 1):

You could be *converting* users from the application format to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about data transfer, the common word is "move"
Moving data is generally the process of exporting from one place or file and importing it into another -- deleting it from the source and adding it to the target. Copying is leaving it in the source and adding it to the target.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Conveyance**](http://gog.is/define+conveyance) - the action or process of transporting or carrying someone or something from one place to another.

**Convey** would certainly differentiate your software, but I doubt it would be very user friendly.

I originally thought you meant importing and exporting between countries, and as that's a possible way to interpret your title, I thought I'd post this anyway for anyone that arrives here thinking the same.

For your exact purposes, **transfer** as suggested in comments before I came along, or **move** as already answered, would both make far more sense in a software environment.

Comment: I had this exact question, `transfer` is the word that works for me.

Answer (score -1):

They're a bit vague, I know, but what about 'action' or 'advance'?