# Is there a word meaning both import and export?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word meaning both import and export?

So I can ask "Is this product both importable and exportable?" like "Is this product ____?"

Comment: Also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167620/what-is-a-single-word-that-means-both-import-and-export

Comment: As asked, this is *not* a duplicate. Or at least, it isn't if "both importable and exportable" is what the OP is looking for. While I'm happy enough with things like *transfer* and *ship* as hypernyms for the **verbs**, that doesn't necessarily make them suitable for that usage. "Importable" and "exportable" are just as (if not more) likely to be to do with legalities. Having said that, I'm not sure I can think of a practical use for "importable and exportable".

Answer (score 0):

"Is this product *transferable*?"

> [transferable:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/transferable) (adj.) capable of being taken from one place to another
>   by public carrier.

Answer (score 0):

*Is this product [**shippable**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/shippable)?*

> shippable: capable of being taken from one place to another by public carrier